# Backup SQL Azure database from the Cloud to on-premises (DPM?)

Tags: azure, scdpm

We currently backup our SQL databases in our data centre using Microsoft DPM.

We are now putting some databases into SQL Azure ( SQL Azure Database ).

How can we backup a database from the could to on premises so we have a copy locally?

Comment: Most effective way would be to backup to cloud storage directly (which is pretty reliable) and then it would be only a matter of downloading the backup file to premises.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing easier than backuping a data to virtual tape libraries IMHO. But at the same time, I got to admit that it was a challenge for me to find a compatible solution with Microsoft DPM. I've ended with StarWind VTL: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-tape-library 
I actually have been using it as some kind of temporary storage for my data-at-rest before it will be offloaded to the cloud. Don't see any reasons why that would not work in reverse order. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this: using **SSIS** (SQL Server Integration Services), using combination of **SSIS and DB creation scripts**, using **Import/Export service in SQL Azure**.

There is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server) maybe could help you.

Answer (score -1):

Azure SQL already have a built-in backup system, you don't need to have a local copy: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups

Comment: It is great that you can backup directly to the cloud, but I would keep at least one copy of the recent data locally. The better option is to follow the 3-2-1 backup rule:
https://www.veeam.com/blog/how-to-follow-the-3-2-1-backup-rule-with-veeam-backup-replication.html